# Close MacBook when using ext. Screen?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have got a MacBook pro with retina display.

Now I want to use a trackpad and keyboard and an external screen on the MacBook.

Can I close the MacBook now to keep working or does this initiate the standby so I can't use the external devices anymore?

Comment: What exactly is "this state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an external display attached with an external mouse/trackpad and keyboard, closing the lid will not put the machine in standby mode. You can keep using the computer with those devices.

Check [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131) Apple link to read the official statement about it.

> Requirements for closed display mode:
>
> - Power adapter
> - External keyboard, mouse, or trackpad
> - External display

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. That was what I want to know ;)